# Fixing multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, echo

I'm trying to make a multidimensional array that should print out like this (without formatting):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> int(0) 
    [1]=> string(5) "Arena" 
    [2]=> string(18) "2012-05-3017:00:00" 
    [3]=> string(18) "2012-05-3000:00:00" 
    [4]=> string(33) "Masquerade Checkin (Participants)" 
}, 

  [1]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> int(0) 
    [1]=> string(10) "Workshop 1"
    [2]=> string(18) "2012-05-3017:00:00"
    [3]=> string(18) "2012-05-3000:00:00"
    [4]=> string(15) "Death Note (Live)" 
},

  [2]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> int(0) 
    [1]=> string(7) "Video 6" 
    [2]=> string(18) "2012-05-3017:00:00"
    [3]=> string(18) "2012-05-3000:00:00"
    [4]=> string(26) "Takeuchi Fan Panel" 
  }
}
```

Notice from the above code  that the inner array() length is always 5.

Here is my code below:

```
$loopsArray = array();
$data=array();
// graphing info come in here. 
foreach ($events as $key => $event) {

    $el=$event['event_location'] ;
    $eln=$event['event_locationName'];
    $ed=$event['event_date'];
    $es=$event['event_start'];
    $ee=$event['event_end'];
    $en=$event['event_name'];

    array_push($loopsArray,$el,$eln, $ed.$es,$ed.$ee,$en);
    array_push($data,$loopsArray);


}
var_dump($data);
```

Here the print out

```
array(27) {
  [0]=> array(5) {
    [0]=> int(0)
    [1]=> string(5) "Arena"
    [2]=> string(18) "2012-05-3017:00:00"
    [3]=> string(18) "2012-05-3000:00:00"
    [4]=> string(33) "Masquerade Checkin (Participants)" 
  } 

  [1]=> array(10) { 
    [0]=> int(0) 
    [1]=> string(5) "Arena" 
    [2]=> string(18) "2012-05-3017:00:00"
    [3]=> string(18) "2012-05-3000:00:00"
    [4]=> string(33) "Masquerade Checkin (Participants)"
    [5]=> int(13)
    [6]=> string(11) "Autograph 1"
    [7]=> string(18) "2012-06-2419:00:00"
    [8]=> string(18) "2012-06-2422:00:00"
    [9]=> string(17) "Parents and Anime" 
  } 
  //... continues 
}
```

Notice that the inner arrays length double each iteration. array(5) array(10) array(15)array(20).

It doubles up to 60 elements in the last inner array. Each inner array should only have 5 elements in them. I don't understand why it is doubling or how to fix it. 
Can you look over my loop and let me know how to fix it?

I have to use this multidimensional array for this code to work in JpGraph.

Comment: quick tip : write `$loopsArray = array();` inside `foreach`

Comment: you are using `$loopsArray` as buffer each step without freeing what you pushed previously. In fact it increments its size by 5 each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TIP :** write `$loopsArray = array();` inside `foreach`

#### better approach

instead of

```
array_push($loopsArray,$el,$eln, $ed.$es,$ed.$ee,$en);
array_push($data,$loopsArray);
```

try this

```
$temp = array ($el,$eln, $ed.$es,$ed.$ee,$en);
$data[] = $temp;
```